# Attempting to load data from existing database using Vue and Sqlite in mobile app

Tags: sqlite, vue.js, nativescript, mobile-application

I'm kinda pressing for time. This is my first Nativescript Vue project. Vue is my first since I understand that it performs better than Angular. I was trying to research on loading populated database but I see couple of example using Angular. (I've never used Angular) There isn't much example of Sqlite using populated database using Vue. So I came across https://www.nativescript.org/blog/data-management-with-sqlite-and-vuex-in-a-nativescript-vue-app and tried to adapt to my project.

I am trying to load faaID and airportName from airportTable by using Sqlite. Two things, 1) how do I get this TabViewItem to immediately call load function once that specific tab is clicked and 2) how do I load all of the data from that database and put it into a list (right now I'm testing using Label)...my goal is put it in the listview as an option for the user to select. my database pilotvoice.db is in ./app

You can see my project at https://github.com/stahlie/first-ns-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, according to https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-sqlite/blob/master/src/README.md

I resolved it by adding {from: "**/*.db"} to webpack.config.js

Answer (score 0):

In your vuex store add a getter

```
getters: {
    allAirports(state, getters) {
        return state.data;
    },
},
```

In your component you can get the loaded data like this

```
load() {
  // perhaps wrap the query action in a promise so you can do...
  this.$store.dispatch("query").then(() => {
      this.airports = this.$store.getters.allAirports;
  }); 
  console.log("Pressed load button");
},
```

Comment: I copied and pasted exactly your codes into my code and still am getting the same result.   It's not pulling or posting any data.

Comment: I don't know if that'll make any different.  I'm using Android and still am not able to load up all of those datas and list them all on the app.   Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Vince Lowe,  Thank you for suggesting me to using getters.   Now  I have more than one table to query.   I have a table for Airport which you have shown me..How do I do it again for Aircraft table and several more ?    Trying to figure that out.

Comment: @Matt Staley, check out my ns project here https://github.com/vlowe85/Flexget it shows breaking the view store into modules for multiple tables